# why the contact sensor in atlas robot can not run in my model?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I define the contact sensors like atlas robot:

```
<gazebo reference="test_link7">
  <sensor name="r_finger3_contact_sensor" type="contact">
      <update_rate>1.0</update_rate>
      <always_on>1</always_on>
      <contact>
        <collision>test_collision7</collision>
        <topic>/test_collision7_contact</topic>
      </contact>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>
  <gazebo reference="test_link3">
      <sensor name="l_finger3_contact_sensor" type="contact">
      <update_rate>1.0</update_rate>
      <always_on>1</always_on>
      <contact>
        <collision>test_collision3</collision>
        <topic>/test_collision7_contact</topic>
      </contact>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>
```

but when I run the model, gazebo show me that the sensors can not be found,so at last,I have to define the sensors at every links. why it can run in atlas and not in my model?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2181/why-the-contact-sensor-in-atlas-robot-can-not-run-in-my-model?/) by [lugd1229](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/79/lugd1229/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 75 on 2013-04-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2013-04-12**:
Are you using a plugin? In addition to defining the sensor in the urdf, Atlas processes much of the contact sensor data in the plugin AtlasPlugin.cpp in the drcsim repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It seems that you are not using plugin. So to view sensor output you must need to echo the contact sensor topic

$ gztopic list

Choose the right topic, then

$ gztopic echo /gazebo/default/physics/contacts

---

Originally posted by [skhan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/266/skhan/) with karma: 131 on 2013-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0